# Parsing Regex with "|" (OR) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-3.6

I´m trying to read a file with the follow regex sentence using python "pattern = (r'(?x)((?<=\Kauid=)|(?<=\Kcomm="nom))[\S]+')" to return both regex parameters,but is Only return the first one

here is my code:

```
import regex
filename = "file.log"
pattern = (r'(?x)((?<=\Kauid=)|(?<=\Kcomm="nom))[\S]+')
matchvalues = []
new_output = []
comm = 'comm="nom-http"'
i = 0

with open(filename, 'r') as audit:
    lines = audit.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        match = regex.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            new_line = match.group()
            print(new_line)
            matchvalues.append(new_line)

matchvalues_size = len(matchvalues)
print(matchvalues)
```

Can you guys help me please?

Comment: Using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) looks for the first location.

Comment: `\K` at the beginning of lookbehind is a nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `\K` is not used within lookbehinds since its meaning is to make the match succeed at the current position and one usually does not want lookbehinds to be part of the current match. So I don't know why you are using variable-length lookbehinds, which require the `regex` package, to begin with. That said, I did not have a problem matching `'comm="nom-http"'` with your regex:

```
>>> pattern = (r'(?x)((?<=\Kauid=)|(?<=\Kcomm="nom))[\S]+')
... comm = 'comm="nom-http"'
... regex.search(pattern, comm)
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='comm="nom-http"'>
```

Note that `comm="nom` is part of the match due to the presence of `\K` in the regex.

But simpler would be to use:

```
pattern = r'((?:auid=|comm="nom)\S+)'
```

So, what is the problem you are having? When you say, "It is only returning the first one", are you then referring to not the pattern but the first occurrence on the line because there may be multiple occurrences? If so, then instead of doing `regex.search`, do `regex.findall`, which will return a list of *string* matches.

```
import re
pattern = r'((?:auid=|comm="nom)\S+)'
matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
```